# Angular - Displaying a number in ion-card

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I want to display a like counter in an ion-card but I can't get it to work.
It doesn't show a number and when I like the card to add up the like counter it displays NaN.

A snippet of my .html file:

```
<ion-label>
 <ion-icon id="thumbs-up" src="assets/icon/likebutton.svg"></ion-icon>
 <ion-label id="like-count">{{thread.likeCount}}</ion-label>
</ion-label>
```

The button from the .html file that adds the likes:

```
<ion-button (click)="[this.thread.likeCount = this.thread.likeCount + 1, this.profilService.addPoints(), this.profilService.updatePoints(this.profilService.pointCounter)]" shape="round" color="primary">
 <ion-icon name="thumbs-up"></ion-icon>
</ion-button>
```

The method I am calling from the .service.ts file that returns the likes:

```
likes: number = 0;
...
getLikes(){
 this.thread.likeCount = this.likes;
 return this.likes;
}
```

My .model.ts file which has the attributes:

```
constructor(
    public id: string,
    public heading: string,
    public user: string,
    public date: Date,
    public description: string,
    public likeCount: number = 0,
    public timeLeft: number
){}
```

And another .page.ts file that creates an ion-card with the like counter:

```
this.threadService.addTicket(this.heading, this.description, this.threadService.getDate(), this.threadService.getLikes()).subscribe();
```

Comment: I am kind of confuse, `thread` is property object form the component?. Are you sure is been updated?, have you try initializing with a constant number to check it shows the value.

Comment: @cabesuon, Thread has all the attributes from the constructor, so it's actually thread.model.ts, thread.service.ts and thread.html.page and the other file is new-thread.page.ts which calls the getLikes() method with AddTicket(). I am pretty sure it updates, when I use something else except thread.likeCount it shows the number.. But I am confused, because I initialize likeCount in the constructor, don't I? If not, please correct me!

Comment: Let me see If I understand, you have a component (the one you are showing the html) that has a property `thread` of type `Thread`, is this correct?. When are you using the service?.